# Restrict Insert based on previous insertion date

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sql-insert

I want to restrict insertion in my table based on some condition.

My table is like

```
col1   col2    Date Create
A        1     04/05/2016
B        2     04/06/2016
A        3     04/08/2016  -- Do not allow insert
A        4     04/10/2016  -- Allow insert
```

So I want to restrict insert based on the number of days the same record was inserted earlier.

As shown in able example, `A` can be inserted again in table only after 4 days of previous insertion not before that.

Any pointers how I can do this in SQL/Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to insert when there **not exists** a record with the same col1 and a too recent date:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2, date_create)
select 'B' as col1, 4 as col2, trunc(sysdate) as date_create from dual ins
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.col1 = ins.col1
  and other.date_create > ins.date_create - 4
);
```

An undesired record would not be inserted thus. However, no exception would be raised. If you want that, I'd suggest a PL/SQL block or a before insert trigger.

Comment: `select 'B', 4, trunc(sysdate) from dual ins` does not work with the given subselect, i suggest `select * from (select 'B' as col1, 4 as col2, trunc(sysdate) as date_create from dual) ins`

Comment: @Frank Ockenfuss: You are right, I forgot the alias names. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas Kettner: imo `select * from (select 'B' ... from dual) ins ` is also required :-)

Comment: @Frank Ockenfuss: That would surprise me.

Comment: @Thomas Kettner: check it out and be surprised

Comment: @Thomas Kettner: with `from dual ins` you give an alias to `dual` table, not to the result set, therefore e.g. `ins.date_create` is not known

Answer (score 0):

If *several processes* write to your table *simultaneously* with possibly conflicting data then oracle database should do the job.

This can be solved by defining a constraint to check if there already exists an entry with the same `col1` value younger than four days.

As far as I know, it is not possible to define such a constraint directly. Instead, define a materialized view and add a constraint on this view.

```
create materialized view mytable_mv refresh on commit as
  select f2.col1, f2.date_create, f1.date_create as date_create_conflict
    from mytable f2, mytable f1
   where f2.col1 = f1.col1
     and f2.date_create > f1.date_create
     and f2.date_create - f1.date_create < 4;
```

This materialized view will contain an entry, if and only if a conflict exists.

Now define a constraint on this view:

```
alter table mytable_mv add constraint check_date_create   
check(date_create=  
      date_create_conflict) deferrable;
```

It is executed when the current transaction is commited (because the materialized view is refreshed - as declared above `refresh on commit`).
This works fine if you insert into your table `mytable` in an autonomous transaction, e.g. for a logging table.

In other cases, you can force the refresh on the materialized view by `dbms_mview.refresh('mytable_mv')` or use another option than `refresh on commit`.